# Django form: fields defined by query result, single view to update multiple objects simultaneously

Tags: python, django, forms, django-models, django-forms

I have the following models in a Django 1.8 project:

```
class MeditationType(models.Model):
    """
    Stores user's meditation types and goals
    """
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modify_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    meditation_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    # Meditation goals per weekday, in minutes
    goal_sun = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(1440)])
    goal_mon = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(1440)])
    goal_tue = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(1440)])
    goal_wed = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(1440)])
    goal_thu = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(1440)])
    goal_fri = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(1440)])
    goal_sat = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(1440)])

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('meditation_types_update', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


class MeditationLog(models.Model):
    """
    Stores user's meditation logs (journal entries)
    """

    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modify_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    meditation_date = models.DateTimeField()

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    meditation_type = models.ForeignKey(MeditationType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # Amount of time (in minutes) this meditation type was practiced on this date
    meditation_minutes = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(1440)])

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('meditation_types_update', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

I would like to build a form with the following fields:
[form fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvBiP.png)

Please note:

- The form will be used to create and update entries.
- The 3 types of meditation used in the example (Focused-attention, Mindfulness and Loving kindness) were created by the user (MeditationType model) so these fields will vary. For some users may be a single meditation type, for other user may be 10 different meditation types. So the form fields have to be defined dynamically according to each user's meditation types.
- When this form is submitted/posted, we have to save multiple instances of the MeditationLog object (one per meditation type).

What would be the most simple and effective way to do that in Django 1.8? Also, if you can think of a better way to build the models (that will make the form building easier), please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will there be any other MeditationType objects?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming you have a ManyToMany field from your User to MeditationType using `through='MeditationLog'`?

Comment: Sardorbek: Thanks for your reply. Yes, each user will create her own meditation types. Maybe 1, 3 or 10 different types per user.

Comment: Rob: Thanks for your reply. I don't have this ManyToMany field. I'm using Django's default user model. One user can have multiple meditation types but each meditation type only belongs to a single user. Could you please elaborate your point?

Comment: @BrunoF: Never mind. I was looking at it wrong. You don't actually need a ManyToMany here. Sorry if I caused any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

After some more research, I finally found something to work with:

https://jacobian.org/writing/dynamic-form-generation/ (Jacob is one of the original founders of Django)

http://www.dougalmatthews.com/2009/Dec/16/nicer-dynamic-forms-in-django/

https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/CookBookNewFormsDynamicFields

http://agiliq.com/blog/2008/10/dynamic-forms-with-django/

http://blog.p3infotech.in/2013/how-to-create-dynamic-forms-in-django/

If you have a similar problem the links above may help.

Thanks to those who replied.